# Most common cause of fire in gadget chargers

Tags: power-electronics

Can someone explain some scenarios where laptop/phone chargers causes fire hazards and what circuitry parts actually fails/heats up that much to cause the dangerous and potentially fatal results?

I am curious to what parts of the electronics inside a compact transformer-based charger is most likely to make it dangerous and why.

I am soon done with the first year of electrical engineering in college, and this still perplexes me. We only calculate and design things that works, not the opposite. And it is frustrating not being able to explain why these things can actually cause fires.

Comment: The doggy designed-in-China-part with no clearances or creapages?

Comment: That + dodgy components, bad manufacturing (i.e.: dirty PCBs with gunk, loose wires, etc), cheap/poor quality flamable materials, etc..

Comment: Recommend reading Ken Shirriff's blog for excellent explanation of the designs and comparisons between models eg http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html?m=1

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on the type of charger.

Older style wall warts were nothing more than a transformer and maybe a diode or four if it was a DC unit. Modern "chargers" are sometimes complete switching regulators with complex electronics.

Each and every component can fail. The more complex the more probability of failure. Overheating and lack of cooling can result in sufficient heat to begin combustion. Shorting or arcing can also result in fire.

Overloading can also cook the unit and make it fail earlier than expected.

Answer (score 2):

These types of chargers almost always use a flyback topology. This is quite a simple and robust design, but like any circuit, it can fail. There are really two contributing reasons as to why cheap chargers can explode or catch fire, which is a rather catastrophic way for anything to fail really.

The first aspect is preventing failures in the first place. As you progress through your course, you will start to learn more about the 'undesirable' parts of circuits and how you mitigate them. For example, almost every switching supply topology you will learn about will fail very quickly in practice if you do not deal carefully with parasitic effects. These typically require appropriate snubbing and suppression circuits to ensure they do not destroy the main parts of the circuit. On cheap power supplies this area is normally where the manufacturer starts cutting corners. The result is that the units will fail more often.

However, even well designed circuits fail through natural part variations. This is where the second aspect comes in - protecting against expected failure modes. In a well designed circuit you layer prevention and protection strategies to reduce the chance of a catastrophic failure occurring to extremely low probabilities. In a cheap power supply it can be very common to just omit this secondary line of protection all together. This is how a expected failure can turn into a catastrophic one.

Ultimately, engineering is all about compromises. You can rarely design the exact circuit you want, but using a careful process you can balance risks against cost to come up with an acceptable solution. Hopefully you can see that there is, sadly, many opportunities in this process to save money at the expense of safety and performance.

Comment: Thanks, my understanding of this was somewhat vague. This helped a lot.